# How do we calculate the following limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, geometric-progressions

The limit to be found is:-

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2+4+...+2^x}{2^x +1}$$

My attempt:-

Taking $ 2^x $ common from numerator and Denominator,

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(2/2^x)+(4/2^x)+...+1}{1 +(1/2^x)} $$

$$  \frac{(2/2^{\infty})+(4/2^{\infty})+...+1}{1 +(1/2^{\infty})} = 1 $$

So the limit is 1.

Is my answer/attempt correct?

Answer (score 2):

For a sum of $n$ first adds of the geometric progression $a$ with $q_a\neq1$ we have:
$$S_n=\frac{a_1(q^n-1)}{q-1}.$$ Id est, it's $$\frac{2(2^x-1)}{2^x+1}=\frac{2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^x}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{2^x}}\rightarrow2.$$

Comment: I didn't understand. Kindly elaborate

Comment: @\Asad Ahmad I added something. See now.

Comment: Okay just summing the GP. I got a bit confused whether to sum the GP or not! But considering that I did not do the sum of GP. Why is the answer different?

Comment: @Asad Ahmad  Theorems about limits work for a finite number of sequences.

Answer (score 0):

By [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) we obtain

$$ \frac{(2+4+...+2^{x+1})-(2+4+...+2^x)}{(2^{x+1}+1)-(2^x +1)}=\frac{2^{x+1}}{2^{x+1}-2^x}=\frac{2}{2-1}=2$$

Your way doesn't work because we have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(2/2^x)+(4/2^x)+...+1}{1 +(1/2^x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^x\frac{1}{2^{x-1}}}{1 +(1/2^x)}$$

and the in the limit the numerator is the geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{x-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is wrong because you consider that all terms in the numerator but the last are $2^k/2^{\infty}$, hence $0$, which is absolutely false. (By the way, why does the last term remain ?)